# Yet another "ssh agent forwarding not working"

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I can ssh from `hostA` to `hostB` and from `hostA` to `hostC` using keys loaded into ssh-agent without any problems.  However, if I do `ssh -A hostB` from `hostA`, then try `ssh hostC` from `hostB`, public key authentication doesn't work and it asks for my password.

Some details:

- I am using `ssh-agent` that comes with OpenSSH, not GNOME Keyring or anything like that.
- Both `ssh -v hostB` from `hostA` and `ssh -v hostC` from `hostA` show:

  ```
  debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
  debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/rhansen/.ssh/id_rsa
  debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
  debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
  ```
- I see my key when I run `ssh-add -L` on `hostB`.
- My key on `hostA` is protected with a password.
- On `hostB`, `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` does NOT contain `AllowAgentForwarding no`.
- All three systems run Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily) with OpenSSH 6.6.1p1.
- When I run `ssh -vvv hostC` from `hostB`, the following is logged:

  ```
  ...
  debug2: key: /home/rhansen/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
  debug2: key: /home/rhansen/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
  debug2: key: /home/rhansen/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
  debug2: key: /home/rhansen/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
  debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
  debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
  debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
  debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
  debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
  debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
  debug1: Trying private key: /home/rhansen/.ssh/id_rsa
  debug3: no such identity: /home/rhansen/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
  debug1: Trying private key: /home/rhansen/.ssh/id_dsa
  debug3: no such identity: /home/rhansen/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
  debug1: Trying private key: /home/rhansen/.ssh/id_ecdsa
  debug3: no such identity: /home/rhansen/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
  debug1: Trying private key: /home/rhansen/.ssh/id_ed25519
  debug3: no such identity: /home/rhansen/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
  debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
  debug3: authmethod_lookup password
  debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
  debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
  debug1: Next authentication method: password
  ```
- If I do `ssh -vvv hostB` from `hostA`, then do `ssh hostC`, the following is logged by `hostA` just before the `hostC` password prompt:

  ```
  debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype auth-agent@openssh.com rchan 2 win 65536 max 16384
  debug2: fd 10 setting O_NONBLOCK
  debug3: fd 10 is O_NONBLOCK
  debug1: channel 2: new [authentication agent connection]
  debug1: confirm auth-agent@openssh.com
  ```
- My `~/.ssh/config` on all systems contains the following uncommon settings (plus some common ones that I don't think are relevant):

  ```
  ControlMaster auto
  ProxyCommand sh ~/.ssh/proxy.sh '%h' '%p' '%r'
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  ```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which agent are you using on hostA – OpenSSH's default ssh-agent? GNOME Keyring? gpg-agent? Pageant?

Comment: Also, anything special in hostB's ~/.ssh/config or /etc/ssh/ssh_config (the client one, not sshd_config)?

Comment: Also, can you `ssh -vv hostC` **from hostA** to confirm that it's really the agent that provides the keys in the working direct connection?

Comment: @grawity:  I updated my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the culprit was the following line in my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I had added that a while back when I was experimenting with lots of keys that were causing "too many attempts" rejections.  I forgot about it when I finished experimenting so I never removed it.  (It had never caused any problems until I started using agent forwarding.)

Answer (score 0):

I am glad to see that you were able to fix the issue on your own.

Your issue was different from the one I was having, but I will add the one I was having just in case someone comes across this post with the one I had.

In my case, the issue was that my home directory had permissions of 775, which ssh does not allow. Not only does the .ssh/ directory need to be 700, and the authorized_keys need to 600, but the home directory itself has to be 755 or below (e.g. 700).